# NSNumberFormatter stringFromNumber not working for Panama currency

Tags: ios, ios7.1, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

I have the following code for getting an amount formatted with currency style from Panama.

```
NSNumberFormatter* numberformatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberformatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_PY"]];
[numberformatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *strReturn =[numberformatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1234]];
```

It should return "B/. 1,234.12" but instead it gives me "B/".

I only have this problem when using Panama locale identifier (es_PY), any other locale I have tried is working ok. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried your code in the iOS Simulator and got `₲ 1.234` as result.

Comment: Yup, you're right, but on iOS 7.1 I used to have the above problem. Thanks anyway for the update.